# Trying to run casperjs with subprocess in python

Tags: javascript, python, casperjs

Having problem using subprocess with Casperjs, try a couple of option already but getting nowhere.

Using a mac, python 2.x

```
import os
import subprocess

CASPER ='/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/bin/casperjs'

SCRIPT = '/Users/doddarliu/Desktop/simple.js'

params = CASPER + ' ' + SCRIPT


stdout_as_string = subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)

print stdout_as_string
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/doddarliu/Desktop/untitled.py", line 11, in <module>
    stdout_as_string = subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/bin/casperjs /Users/doddarliu/Desktop/simple.js' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: subprocess.check_output(params, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
and print the output of the exception

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/doddarliu/Desktop/untitled.py", line 11, in <module>
    stdout_as_string = subprocess.check_output(params, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/bin/casperjs /Users/doddarliu/Desktop/simple.js' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: `try...except CalledProcessError as e: print e.output`